# Method override in Groovy

Tags: inheritance, groovy

How can one override a method from the superclass in a class that extends the superclass, in Groovy? The Java way is not working, as both methods (the one in the superclass and the one in the subclass) are being executed. For example:

```
class SuperClass {

  SuperClass(){

    println("This is the superclass")
  }

  def awaitServer(){
    println("awaiting server in the superclass")
  }

}


class SubClass extends SuperClass{


  SubClass(){
    println("This is the subclass")
  }

  @Override
  def awaitServer(){
    println("awaiting server in the subclass")
  }

}

//////
SubClass sb = new SubClass()
sb.awaitServer()
```

The output i get is:

```
awaiting server in the superclass
awaiting server in the subclass
```

As you can see both methods are executed, when i'm overriding the method of the super class in the subclass. Why is this happening? How is the method overriding done in Groovy?

I've searched on the web, but I'm not able to figure it out. Can someone provide a sample or a simple example?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I think you've lost something in your translation to an example as that works...

Comment: it would print either of the two and not both - regardless what is happening.  unless you have forgotten in your example, that there is a `super` call in the subclass in `awaitServer`.

Comment: So the  bottom line is, this code is not the code that the OP was actually executing.  See comments about @TaskAction at bottom.  Misleading question.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add `def`. This code works correctly:

```
class SuperClass {
   SuperClass(){
      println("This is the superclass")
   }

   def awaitServer() {
      println("awaiting server in the superclass")
   }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass{

   SubClass() {
      println("This is the subclass")
   }

   @Override
   def awaitServer() {
      println("awaiting server in the subclass")
   }
}

SubClass sb = new SubClass()
sb.awaitServer()
```

It outputs:

```
This is the superclass 
This is the subclass 
awaiting server in the subclass
```

Have a look at the output below:

```
[opal@opal-mac-2]/tmp % cat lol.groovy 
class SuperClass {
   SuperClass(){
      println("This is the superclass")
   }

   def awaitServer() {
      println("awaiting server in the superclass")
   }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass{

   SubClass() {
      println("This is the subclass")
   }

   @Override
   def awaitServer() {
      println("awaiting server in the subclass")
   }
}

SubClass sb = new SubClass()
sb.awaitServer()

[opal@opal-mac-2]/tmp % groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.4.0 JVM: 1.8.0_05 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
[opal@opal-mac-2]/tmp % groovy lol.groovy 
This is the superclass
This is the subclass
awaiting server in the subclass
```

With groovy 1.8.6:

```
[opal@opal-mac-2]/tmp % gvm use groovy 1.8.6
==== BROADCAST =================================================================
* 27/02/15: Springboot 1.1.11.RELEASE has been released on GVM. #spring
* 27/02/15: Springboot 1.2.2.RELEASE has been released on GVM. #spring
* 26/02/15: Grails 3.0.0.M2 has been released on GVM. #grailsframework
================================================================================

Stop! groovy 1.8.6 is not installed.
Do you want to install it now? (Y/n): Y

Downloading: groovy 1.8.6

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 15.5M  100 15.5M    0     0  2666k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 3716k

Installing: groovy 1.8.6
/Users/opal/.gvm/tmp/groovy-1.8.6 -> /Users/opal/.gvm/groovy/1.8.6
Done installing!


Using groovy version 1.8.6 in this shell.
[opal@opal-mac-2]/tmp % groovy lol.groovy 
This is the superclass
This is the subclass
awaiting server in the subclass
```

Comment: Hi Opal
Yes, i had forgotten to write "def" in this post, but in my code i have the def before the method name. But still both methods are being executed.

Comment: What groovy version You use?

Comment: I'm using **Groovy: 1.8.6**

Comment: Hi Opal,
Sorry for the late reply. I finally figured it out why i was getting this weird behavior. It didn't have to do so much with how inheritance and overriding work in Java.
In my code(which is not the above. That was just a simple example), I had marked the method of the superclass with the TaskAction annotation. And that was causing the weird behavior.
It turns out, that when a method in a class is marked with the TaskAction, and you override that method in a subclass, the method of the superclass will still be executed, even though you are overriding it.

Comment: Dunno if this is intended behavior or is a bug. I'm not that advanced yet to have known this. Found it just by playing with the code.

Comment: So it seems that this is basically a gradle question :)

Comment: Well, at that time, i was more suspicious about groovy and it didn't cross my mind that an annotation could give this kind of behavior.